# Does $\frac{b}{s} \in S^{-1} I$ directly implies that $b \in I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity $1_R$, $0 \not \in S\subseteq R$ be a multiplicative set, and $I\subseteq R$ be an ideal of $R$.Consider the ring of quotients $S^{-1}I$.

I was trying to prove a theorem, and I proved almost everything, but stuck at showing that if $\frac{b}{s} \in I $, then $b \in I$, so my question is

> Does $\frac{b}{s}  \in S^{-1} I$ directly implies that $b \in I$ ?

The definition only says that for $i \in I, s' \in S$ satisfying $\frac{b}{s} = \frac{i}{s'}$, i.e $\exists s_1 \in S \quad s.t \quad s_1 (s'b - si) = 0,$, the equivalence class $b/s \in S^{-1}I$. but since $R$ is not necessarily an integral domain, I couldn't derive anything useful from this relation.

**Edit:**

In the original theorem, $I$ and $b$ has some other properties, but what I want to understand in this question is that whether I need to look for other thing, or I'm done but just I haven't realized it.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring_and_a_module) for the definition of the equivalence class $b/s$.

Comment: As I see it, it only means there exists $s'\in S$ such that $s'b\in I$.

Comment: @Bernard I think so too.

Comment: However, it would be true if $I$ were a prime ideal (not meeting $S$)

Comment: @Bernard in the original theorem, I'm trying to prove that $I$ is a prime ideal; I assumed it is not the case, and examined every case separately.

Comment: @amWhy: Why did you remove the tag [tag:localization]?  This seems like a paradigmatic example of a question that should have that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is false. For example, let $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}R = \Z$, $P = 3\Z$, so $S = \Z \setminus 3\Z$, and $I = 6\Z$.  Then
$$
I_P = S^{-1} I = \left\{\frac{6m}{n} : m,n \in \Z, 3 \nmid n\right\} \, .
$$
Since $2 \in S$ then $\frac{3}{1} = \frac{6}{2} \in I_P$, but $3 \notin I$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andre.